# Запуск docker контейнера с инкрементируемым именем

Tags: linux, docker

Подскажите как можно запускать контейнеры с автоматически инкрементируемым именем, через переменные среды т.е:

```
docker run --name name_${COUNT} my-image
```

Эта команда не работает (Invalid container name), но возможно ли как либо запустить подобное?